# Where can I find high-quality editable slides for teaching git?

Tags: resource-request, git

I would like to teach my software engineering students `git` and to introduce key ideas in a presentation. Creating slides from scratch does not seem like a good use of time, since there are probably better ones already out there that I could use. I have found PDFs of presentations, but they are not editable, and I do not know their license. I am not interested in materials specific to a given site, such as GitHub or GitLab. I would like to find high-quality slides (in PowerPoint, Google Slides, or some other standard format) that I can freely edit and use.

Comment: If you ever find out how to teach (the use of) git, then please consider adding an answer to https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/2897/204

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tom Preston-Werner](https://tom.preston-werner.com/2009/05/19/the-git-parable.html)'s wonderful [Git Parable](https://tom.preston-werner.com/2009/05/19/the-git-parable.html) has been made into a [presentation](https://github.com/jherland/git_parable) by Johan Herland. The slides, which are available in ODP and Google Slides formats, are  licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International License.

Answer (score 1):

I know of no freely/commercially available presentations, but I do know of a site that feels a lot like a presentation as you use it: [Learn Git Branching](https://learngitbranching.js.org/). It's interactive and gives a hands-on intro to the most basic git features as it explains them. Plus, everything is visualized in real-time, so you and your students get instant feedback on what the command did to the pretend repo.

My thought is that you could either use that site in front of your students (or perhaps just use git itself and some sample files), or you could have your students use the site and follow along with you.

Honestly, from my own experience, that site (along with using git on small practice projects) was exponentially more educational/memorable than *any* presentation I've seen so far at my university, or found online. I don't just agree that making your own presentation would be a waste of your time, but I think you should consider a different format all together. Git, just like programming, is better learned through doing.

Comment: Thank you. I agree that Learn Git Branching is a great site. I was already planning to have students make use of it.